# django rest_framework with basic auth, how to consume api with django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created an API with basic authentication and I was wondering how can i consume it with an username and password

this is my endpoint

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/Clerk/
```

I try to consume it by

```
def display_clerk_view(request):
    displaytable = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/Clerk/')
    jsonobj = displaytable.json()
    return render(request, 'clearance/clerk_view.html', {"ClerkClearanceItems": jsonobj})
```

this block of code and it's giving me error *Unauthorized: /Clerk/*

I'm planning to use django all-auth with google as provider but for now I want to know how consuming api with authentication works

this is the tutorial i'm following https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/basic-authentication-django-rest-framework/?tab=article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case, you are requesting to "/Clerk/" but it's returning unauthorized.
There are two ways to fix this issue:

1. Remove authentication permission from your view (if function-based view, remove the decorator login_required or is_authenticated condition from the view. If class-based view, add "permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]")

[You'r given link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/basic-authentication-django-rest-framework/?tab=article): There are used a decorator called "permission_classes", You can replace "@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])" with "@permission_classes([AllowAny])

2. If you want authorized action, you can just create a token by username and password.

There are many ways to create tokens, the most popular one is simple-jwt.To learn more follow the link: [Simple JWT DOCS](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

Comment: Well I want it to have permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] so not anyone can access it if I make it public, What I am curious is how to consume the api that have authenticate

Comment: do i add something at my `def display_clerk_view`